# Generating a list of uniquely name elements based on a for i in range statement

Tags: python, list

I have:

```
Number = 4
for i in range(1, Number):
    grwth = ('r'+'C')
print(grwth)
```

But what I want is for 'rC' to have a unique name each time it is printed. So, if Number is entered to be 4, grwth should be a list of [rC, rC2, rC3, rC4] Like that. Is that possible to do ?

Comment: `grwth = ['rC{}'.format(i)  for i in range(1, 4)]`

Comment: `grwth = []` before loop and `grwth.append('rC{}'.format(i))`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get at that. Here's one using list comprehension and string formatting.

```py
number = 4
grwth = [f"rC{i}" for i in range(1, number + 1)]
```

Comment: So basically a for i in range statement within that in itself?

Comment: How can i be placed within a string then?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do want the result to be a single string value that would print like: 
"rC1, rC2, rC3, rC4"?

Comment: I understand, I tested and it worked. What I am wondering is, how can {i} be in the string?

Comment: If you're using python3 >= 3.6, you have what they call `f-strings`. https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible to do ?

Yep! Let's start by initializing `grwth` as a list and appending to it, rather than assigning:

```
number = 4
grwth = []
for i in range(1, number):
    grwth.append('r'+'C')
print(grwth)
```

This results in `['rC', 'rC', 'rC']`. The values are all the same because we're appending the same thing every time. But that variable `i` is accessible from inside our loop, so we can use it to append something different every time!

```
number = 4
grwth = []
for i in range(1, number):
    grwth.append('r'+'C'+str(i))
print(grwth)
```

This gives us `['rC1', 'rC2', 'rC3']`! Note that `i` is an integer, so we cast it to a number before appending. We could alternatively use any number of string formatting operations to create the string.

Note that there are any number of further improvements we could make to this code; we could use a list comprehension, tweak our use of `range` to be a little more intuitive, etc. But this should serve as a good starting point!